# Looking for title YA Time travel 1970s England to Victorian

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, young-adult

I'm looking for the name of a book that I read when I was a kid.

Teenage girl in moden day England ends up going back to 1880's at Christmas time.  The most vivid thing I remember is an all blue Christmas tree and how it was very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was it "[Mirror of Danger](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3197997-mirror-of-danger)" by Pamela Sykes (aka "Come Back Lucy")

Comment: That is it!  You are amazing.  Gotta find it now.